# Filtering with silence

Tags: silence

The `silence` package filters out Warning and Error messages .. is it possible to filter out Info messages such as

```
Package mdframed Info: mdframed works in twoside mode on input line 207.
Package mdframed Info: mdframed detected package amsthm
        changed the theorem header of amsthm
        (mdframed) on input line 121.
LaTeX Font Info:    Font shape `LGR/txr/m/sc' will be
     (Font)         scaled to size 10.0pt on input line 20.
File: 1327.eps Graphic file (type eps)
```

These messages are shown only for info and I want to suppress them in order to locate more easily the real warnings and errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following commands can be redefined:

- `\PackageInfo`
- `\@font@info`
- `\@latex@info`

They all send (non-critical) information out to the terminal. You can do this before `\documentclass`:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\PackageInfo}[2]{}% Remove package information
\renewcommand{\@font@info}[1]{}% Remove font information
\renewcommand{\@latex@info}[1]{}% Remove LaTeX information
\makeatother

\documentclass...
```