# Suppress providing message of package

Tags: errors, packages, warnings

The package `infwarerr` is included in quite a few packages (by means of `\RequirePackage{infwarerr}`and most of the times an option with a date) and it results (once) in the line:

```
Package: infwarerr 2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
```

I would like to suppress this message, is this possible?

I found the question [Filtering with silence](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/398856/44119) but this did not have the desired effect.

Comment: every package issues such a line, so why do you want to suppress only for this package?

Comment: I would bet it is making false positives when searching the log for `error` @UlrikeFischer :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle oh, well the easy solution would be to ask infwarerr to change the text. ;-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle nearly I want it to suppress it because of the "warning.

Comment: Suppressing the the text of the Providing message (or similar) for other packages would not be a show stopper for me.

Comment: you could just fix your search to `warning[^/]` :-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I know but I'm looking for a more general approach so that the search is independent of the exact text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you *really* want this you can load the package first with the message disabled, so it will not reload when called from packages.

```
\makeatletter
\let\@@protected@wlog\protected@wlog
\def\protected@wlog#1{\wlog{package info suppressed}}
\RequirePackage{infwarerr}
\let\protected@wlog\@@protected@wlog
\makeatother
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\end{document}
```

has  log entries

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/infwarerr/infwarerr.sty
package info suppressed
)
```

...

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/latex/hyperref/hyperref.sty
Package: hyperref 2023-02-07 v7.00v Hypertext links for LaTeX

(/usr/local/texlive/2023/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ltxcmds/ltxcmds.sty
Package: ltxcmds 2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
)
```

showing just the one package is affected

Comment: This is what I like and want. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed, scanning the log file for "error" seems like the intended purpose. Perhaps the brute force approach (my only method) would be to copy `infwarerr.sty` to the document directory, where it will have precedence. Then manually edit that copy to remove the message. Might also work with texmf-local, as long as the package is not often updated.